# Select XML nodes as attributes

Tags: xml, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, xquery, sqlxml

I am assuming the answer to my question is going to be something simple which I can't figure out myself. Here is the scenario:

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 where a table has an XML column where the data is saved in the following format:

```
<Person>
    <firstName>John</firstName>
    <lastName>Lewis</lastName>
</Person>
```

The `Person` node can have any number of child-nodes for which the element names might be different (not known beforehand). I am looking for a query to return an XML which has the values for all the nodes as attributes.

So the output for the above XML should be:

```
<Person firstName="John" lastName="Lewis"/>
```

I can't think of a query to get the above output. I don't want to use a query like

```
Select 
      PersonColumn.value('(/Person/firstName)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS '@firstName'
    , PersonColumn.value('(/Person/lastName)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS '@lastName'
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyTable.MyPrimaryKey=1
FOR XML PATH('Person'), TYPE
```

since I don't know what nodes might there be under the `Person` node.

Comment: You say "*The Person node can have any number of descendants for which the names might be different*".  Please provide an example of this (multiple descendants with different names), and what you expect as a result.  The single-descendant example you gave isn't helpful.

Comment: What i meant was the Person node might not just have firstName and lastName. It can have more nodes under it but none of the nodes will repeat, viz., firstName will come up only once. I hope that made it more clear. The word Descendant might have confused you. My example shows 2 Descendants to Person which are firstName and lastName. Maybe the more appropriate term would have been Child Nodes.

Comment: Ahh, you mena that the *element* names are unknown?

Comment: This would be trivial with a CLR (C#) stored proc. Is that an option?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580077/how-do-i-pivot-on-an-xml-columns-attributes-in-t-sql?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to do this

```
select
    PersonColumn.query('
        element Person {
            for $i in /Person/*
            return attribute {local-name($i)} {string($i)}
        }
    ')
from MyTable
```

but it turns out that it's impossible to use dynamic attribute names

```
XQuery [MyTable.PersonColumn.query()]: Only constant expressions are supported for the name expression of computed element and attribute constructors.: select PersonColumn.query(' element Person { for $i in /Person/* return attribute {local-name($i)} {string($i)} } ') from MyTable
```

So best I can do so far is

```
select 
    cast(
        '<Person ' + 
        (
            select
                PersonColumn.query('
                for $i in /Person/*
                return concat(local-name($i), "=""", data($i), """")
                ').value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
            for xml path('')
        ) + '/>'
    as xml)
from MyTable
```

It's also possible to do this

```
select
    cast(
        '<Person ' + 
        PersonColumn.query('
            for $i in /Person/*
            return concat(local-name($i), "=""", data($i), """")
        ').value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') +
        '/>'
      as xml)
from MyTable
```

but it will not work if your data contains some characters like `<` `>` and so on

Comment: +1: your "best so far" is actually pretty darn good.  One of my favorites, ever.

Comment: This seems pretty close. I will give it a try. Thanks

Comment: This worked great. For the scenario I am using this, there wont be any `<` or `>`. Thank You.

Comment: @Roman: Do you have a link where i can refer to the various things i can use in `PersonColumn.query`? I just realized its not just `<` and `>` where it breaks but even for `&` so need to know is there anything which will read the raw xml than convert `&amp;` to `&` which is happening currently with `data($i)`

Comment: that thing inside query is called XQuery, you can read about it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189075.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you essentially want to `PIVOT` on the names of elements that are direct children of the Person node. If you must do this all in TSQL you must construct the query dynamically. See [How do I Pivot on an XML column's attributes in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580077/how-do-i-pivot-on-an-xml-columns-attributes-in-t-sql?rq=1) for inspiration. In that case the pivot expression was also an attribute value, while in your case it's an element name.

I do feel obliged to point out the obvious -- that such a solution is likely to perform poorly, the results be difficult to consume (since column names and count are unknown) and may be susceptible to sql injection attacks depending on the context.

Comment: A normal PIVOT cannot do this, it could only be done with a dynamic PIVOT.  Considering that you would still have to shred it out from XML to a SQL virtual table, do the PIVOT, and then re-compose it back into XML, there seems to be too much hand-waving here without actual examples.