# Shred multiple XML's into one relational table

Tags: sql, xml

I have a column containing XML's that looks like this:

```
<event name="QueryEnd" package="AS" timestamp="2017-03-23T13:14:17.192Z">
  <data name="CurrentTime">
    <value>2017-03-23T13:14:17.193Z</value>
  </data>
  <data name="StartTime">
    <value>2017-03-23T13:14:17.188Z</value>
  </data>
  <data name="EndTime">
    <value>2017-03-23T13:14:17.193Z</value>
  </data>
  <data name="EventClass">
    <value>10</value>
    <text>QUERY_END</text>
  </data>
  <data name="EventSubclass">
    <value>0</value>
  </data>
```

I want shred this XML to a table with data names as columnnames and the value as data. Does anyone have an idea how to do this in a query?

Comment: Which RDBMS?  Sql Server? Oracle?  MySql?  other?

Comment: If ti's for SQL Server, it's a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580077/how-do-i-pivot-on-an-xml-columns-attributes-in-t-sql

Comment: Are the values for `/data/@name` a closed set? Do you know all of them in advance (even if not each name must be contained in each XML)?