# Flatten SQL row 'properties' result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

SQL Server 2005

I have the following result set:

```
ID  name    prop    value
--------------------------
1   one     Prop1   va1_1_1
1   one     Prop2   val_1_2
2   two     Prop1   val_2_1
2   two     Prop2   val_2_2
3   three   Prop2   val_3_2
4   four    Prop1   val_4_1
4   four    Prop2   val_4_2
```

How can I flatten it to get an output of

```
ID  name    Prop1       Prop2
---------------------------------
1   one     val_1_1     val_1_2
2   two     val_2_1     val_2_2
3   three   val_3_2     NULL
4   four    val_4_1     val_4_2
```

**Note:** The number of properties (`Prop1`, `Prop2`) is arbitrary and can be many.

Comment: Is it always just `Prop1` and `Prop2` or is the number of properties dynamic so you need a dynamic amount of columns?

Comment: Dynamic, so an arbitrary number of columns. Updated question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [MSDN: Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx).

It has a very good example of what you are trying to do.

This will give you the desired result.

```
Select  *
From    (
        Select  ID,name,prop,value 
        from    YourTable 
        ) P
PIVOT ( max(value) For Prop in (Prop1,Prop2) ) as pvt
Order By ID
```

Please note, you need to support arbitrary number of prop values. In that case one solution could be to build this script dynamically and execute it.

**EDIT:**
To make it complete, here is the SQL that would work for arbitrary number of prop values -

```
Declare @Value as NVarChar(Max)
Set @Value =    'Select *
                From    (
                        Select  ID,name,prop,value 
                        from    YourTable 
                        ) P
                PIVOT ( max(value) For Prop in ('

Select @Value = @Value +  Prop + ','
from (  Select  Distinct Prop
        From YourTable) YT

Set @Value = Left(@Value, Len(@Value)-1)

Set @Value = @Value + ') ) as pvt Order By ID'
Exec(@Value)
```

Comment: I've seen that before. But it seems the example (and all other PIVOT examples) revolve around using some type of aggregate function (`SUM`, `MAX`). I don't see how I can apply that to this.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how you can use MAX() to get what you want.

Comment: That is not what OP is looking for. OP wants Pivot with Dynamic Columns.

Comment: @Ardian - That is why I've stated, OP will need to generate this script dynamically to support arbitrary number of prop values.

Comment: This works. Final question, how can I have the query concatenate the content in `value`if there exists more than one row with the same `ID` and `prop`?

Comment: I don't think you can concatenate strings, it only works on [Aggregate Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx). You can get the same effect by concatenating the desired items in a temp table and pivoting this temp table instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT ID,Name, (SELECT prop FROM table t1 WHERE prop=prop1 AND ID = table.id) AS Prop1,
    (SELECT prop FROM table t2 WHERE prop=prop2 AND ID = table.id) AS Prop2
    FROM table
```

Comment: you've got the prop1 alias used 2 times, and the question has been updated to state dynamic column numbers.

Comment: I saw that the question after first submitting.  Well in case   something static could be useful in the end.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

- [Pivots with Dynamic Columns in SQL Server 2005/2008](http://www.sqlprof.com/blogs/sqldev/archive/2008/04/12/pivots-with-dynamic-columns-in-sql-server-2005-2008.aspx)
- [SQL Dynamic Pivot - how to order columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122117/sql-dynamic-pivot-how-to-order-columns)