# converting from long dataset to wide dataset in SQL with an arbitrary number of group variables

Tags: sql, pivot

Suppose you have repeated measures on individuals over time displayed vertically and you wish to convert that to a wide display, e.g. from

```
family | year | salary
fam1   | 2002 | 80
fam1   | 2003 | 82
fam1   | 2008 | 90
fam2   | 1996 | 45
fam3   | 2002 | 70
fam3   | 2003 | 72
```

to

```
family | salary1996 | salary2002 | salary2003 | salary2008
fam1   | 45         | .          | .          | .
fam2   | .          | 80         | 82         | 90
fam3   | .          | 70         | 72         | .
```

The problem is that there is arbitrary number of possible values for "year".

Comment: For what database?  A dynamic number of years guarantees needing to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: Why would you convert to a wide table? The way you have it to begin with is proper for your situation.

Comment: @Nik We're merging with a "family" level dataset that is very large. We need rectangular data for statistical software. Replicating observations from the family level data would be too large and unstable to do anything useful.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using SQL Server, this is what you are looking for:

- [Pivots with Dynamic Columns in SQL Server 2005/2008](http://www.sqlprof.com/blogs/sqldev/archive/2008/04/12/pivots-with-dynamic-columns-in-sql-server-2005-2008.aspx) (Best article on the subject I've read so far)
- [SQL Dynamic Pivot - how to order columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122117/sql-dynamic-pivot-how-to-order-columns) (from our very own StackOverflow)

**Update**

Still assuming you are using SQL Server 2005 or above, here is the code:

```
DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @sqlquery VARCHAR(2000)

SELECT  @cols = STUFF(( SELECT distinct  '], [' + cast([year] as varchar)
                        FROM YourTable FOR XML PATH('') ), 1, 2, '') + ']'


SET @sqlquery = 'SELECT * FROM
      (SELECT family,  [year], [salary]
       FROM YourTable) base
       PIVOT (SUM(salary) FOR [year]
       IN (' + @cols + ')) AS finalpivot'

EXECUTE ( @sqlquery )
```