# Can I use PIVOT without the brackets?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, pivot, pivot-table

```
PIVOT 
(
    count(DueCount) FOR dueLibraries.s_folder IN ([Assembly Report-TUL],[Balance-TUL],[BOM-TUL],[Hydrostatic-TUL],[Inspection-TUL],[IOM Manual-TUL],[MTR-TUL],[NDT-TUL],[Performance-TUL],[Inputs - TUL],[Transmitted])
) as MonthlyTally
```

I rather just have this:

```
PIVOT 
(
    count(DueCount) FOR dueLibraries.s_folder IN (select * from dueLibraries)
) as MonthlyTally
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: The brackets are needed because of the spaces and dashes in your names.

Comment: Ugh. Now I'm gonna need to do string manipulation in SQL.... Mercy.

Comment: In any event, the syntax does not allow you to replace the explicit list of columns in the PIVOT clause, with a mask (to say nothing about using SELECT there). If the number of values/columns is undefined then you probably want to do a [dynamic PIVOT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122117/sql-dynamic-pivot-how-to-order-columns).

Comment: Could one of you make your comment an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is two-fold, as it seems.

First of all, the identifiers in your first snippet's `IN` list are *delimited identifiers*. They have to be delimited with square brackets because they [do not obey the rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx) for *regular identifiers* in Transact-SQL (particularly, because they include spaces and hyphens).

The second part of your question is about replacing the explicit list of columns with something like a mask, to make the list dynamic. Now, there's no available syntax for that, and your only option seems to be a dynamic query with a PIVOT clause. [Here's one example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122117/sql-dynamic-pivot-how-to-order-columns) of how it can be implemented.