# Pivoting with Sum function in tsql

Tags: t-sql, pivot-table

I have data in following format

```
Client       Business Unit    Year  Quarter     USD Amt
BalckRock    Pricing          2010  Q1          234
BalckRock    Pricing          2010  Q2          343
BalckRock    Pricing          2010  Q3          545
BalckRock    Pricing          2010  Q4          5435
BalckRock    Pricing          2011  Q1          5425
BalckRock    Pricing          2011  Q2          3524
BalckRock    Pricing          2011  Q3          54
BalckRock    Pricing          2011  Q4          5425
BalckRock    Pricing          2012  Q1          545
BalckRock    Pricing          2012  Q2          5445
BalckRock    Pricing          2012  Q3          545
BalckRock    Pricing          2012  Q4          4545
BalckRock    Sales            2010  Q1          23
BalckRock    Sales            2010  Q2          3434
BalckRock    Sales            2010  Q3          4234
BalckRock    Sales            2010  Q4          4234
BalckRock    Sales            2011  Q1          3423
BalckRock    Sales            2011  Q2          1
BalckRock    Sales            2011  Q3          1341
BalckRock    Sales            2011  Q4          434
BalckRock    Sales            2012  Q1          421
BalckRock    Sales            2012  Q2          42
BalckRock    Sales            2012  Q3          434
BalckRock    Sales            2012  Q4          4214
```

And I want it in following format

```
Client        Business Unit    2010    2011    2012
BalckRock     Pricing          6557    14428   11080
BalckRock     Sales            11925   5199    5111
```

Basically the sum of USD amnt year wise, but years as the column heading

Can anyone help me in this ?

Comment: Post your existing sql code, what have you tried?

Comment: check code from this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122117/sql-dynamic-pivot-how-to-order-columns?rq=1

Answer (score 6):

There are different ways, you can use `PIVOT` (static or dynamic depending on your needs) or you can simply use a `CASE`:

```
SELECT  Client,
        [Business Unit],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [Year] = 2010 THEN [USD Amt] ELSE 0 END) [2010],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [Year] = 2011 THEN [USD Amt] ELSE 0 END) [2011],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [Year] = 2012 THEN [USD Amt] ELSE 0 END) [2012]
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Client, [Business Unit]
```

Using `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (  SELECT Client, [Business Unit], [USD Amt], [Year]
        FROM YourTable) T
PIVOT (SUM([USD Amt]) FOR [Year] IN ([2010],[2011],[2012])) PT
```

Comment: it is worth noting that the reason why there's a sub-select in the FROM clause is because PIVOT automatically groups by what ever columns are not used in the PIVOT itself. So in this example [USD Amt] and [Year] are in the PIVOT so everything will be grouped by [Client] + [Business Unit]

Answer (score 5):

You can easily use a [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for this. As the other have said you can use a Static Pivot that you code the columns that you want or you can use a Dynamic Pivot, which get the list of columns at run-time.

Static Pivot (See [Sql Fiddle for Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/95271/4))

```
select *
from
(
  select client, businessunit, year, USD_Amount
  from t
) x
pivot
(
  sum(USD_Amount)
  for year in ([2010], [2011], [2012])
) p
```

But for this, I might recommend a dynamic Pivot so you don't have to change you code when you get into a new year.  (See [Sql Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/95271/2))

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)


select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(year) 
                    from t
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT client, businessunit, ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select client, businessunit, year, USD_Amount
                from t
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(USD_Amount)
                for year in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Both queries will produce the same results.  However, the plus with the dynamic pivot is that when you have data from additional years, you will not have to update the query to include those fields.  The first part of the query gets the list of the `distinct years` in your table, it then uses that list of `years` to determine the `SUM` that you are looking for.

Comment: You do not need a dynamic Pivot if you use instead of current year the difference to the current year: (year(getdate()) - year) as difYear and in the for:  FOR [difYear] IN ( [2], [1], [0], the select could be like: [2] AS 'Previous Year-1', [1] AS 'Previous Year', [0] AS 'Current Year'

Answer (score 0):

-- Pivot table with one row and five columns

```
SELECT Client  Business Unit   Year    Quarter USD Amt,[2010],[2011],[2012]
FROM
(SELECTClient  Business Unit   Year    Quarter USD Amt 
    FROM Table) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
sum(USD Amt)
FOR Year IN ([2010], [2011], [2012])
) AS PivotTable;
```