# How to group by data from rows to columns

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have a table as below (Time sheet)..I want to flatten the table to Flattened_TimeSheet..Can I use group by here? If not could someone help me with the query.

[image]

Comment: You can go with two approaches either using `case` or `pivot`. [Here is pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11348562/pivoting-with-sum-function-in-tsql)

Comment: Column value for 1-C should be 3 instead of 4, right?

Comment: yes, it was a typo. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
select ID,
sum(case when type='a' then hour else 0 end) as A,
sum(case when type='b' then hour else 0 end) as B,
sum(case when type='c' then hour else 0 end) as C
from TimeSheet
where type in ('a', 'b', 'c')
group by ID
```

Comment: Is `where type in ('a', 'b', 'c')` condition required?

Comment: Not really, but in this case for this search, its more fast ;)