# Sort Columns For Dynamic Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following SQL query where the columns created are out of order and I am not quite sure how to fix it.

```
SELECT rhead.rhcust AS [Cust ID], rdetl.rdextp AS [Inv Amt], rhead.rhivdt AS [Inv Date]
INTO #TempTable
FROM rhead
LEFT OUTER JOIN rdetl
    ON rhead.rhinvc = rdetl.rdinvc
WHERE rhead.rhivdt >= '01-01-2012' AND rhead.rhivdt <= '12-25-12'

ALTER DATABASE Vista_TM SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME('Month'+cast(DATEPART(m, [Inv Date]) as varchar(2))) 
                    from #TempTable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT [Cust ID],' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
                SELECT [Cust ID], [Inv Amt],
                  ''Month''+cast(DATEPART(m, [Inv Date]) as varchar(2)) MonthNo
                FROM #TempTable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum([Inv Amt])
                for MonthNo in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)

DROP TABLE #TempTable
```

I believe it has to do something with this section of the query:

```
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME('Month'+cast(DATEPART(m, [Inv Date]) as varchar(2))) 
                    from #TempTable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')
```

I did try messing around with the answer posted in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122117/sql-dynamic-pivot-how-to-order-columns) but I could not get the query to run.  I am hoping someone can help.

**Edit** I just noticed my rows are out of order and would like to sort by [Cust ID] as well.

Comment: Your thoughts are right, you could just add `ORDER BY DATEPART(m, [Inv Date])` after `#TempTable` but before `FOR XML PATH('')`. On an unrelated, and not very important note, I would consider it better practice to use `EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @Query`, rather than 'EXECUTE(@Query)`, [Aaron Bertrand](http://stackoverflow.com/users/61305/) has also [blogged about it](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp_executesql) in his bad habits to kick series.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can adjust the order of the fields in a dynamic pivot query by adding an `ORDER BY` when you set your `@cols` string:

```
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME('Month'+cast(DATEPART(m, [Inv Date]) as varchar(2))) 
                    from #TempTable
                    ORDER BY ....
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')
```

Update:  Missed the `DISTINCT` at first, when using `DISTINCT` you'll have to use a subquery and then `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' +   QUOTENAME(ColName) 
                    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT 'Month'+cast(DATEPART(m, [Inv Date]) as varchar(2)) ColName
                          FROM #TempTable
                          )sub
                    ORDER BY ColName
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')
```

You may need to add a 'sort' field into your subquery if you can't simply use the column name, and you can add any fields to the subquery so long as they don't disrupt the `DISTINCT` list.  For example:

```
SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' +   QUOTENAME(ColName) 
                    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT 'Month'+cast(DATEPART(m, [Inv Date]) as varchar(2)) ColName
                                          ,CASE WHEN field = 'something' THEN 1
                                                WHEN field = 'something else' THEN 2
                                                ELSE 3
                                           END as Sort
                                          ,Cust_ID
                          FROM #TempTable
                          )sub
                    ORDER BY Sort,Cust_ID
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')
```

Comment: In my particular example I tried both ORDER BY `[Inv Date]` and `QUOTENAME` neither which worked and the error message says _ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified._  I also tried `[Inv Amt]`

Comment: That sorts it thanks!  Unfortunately I am doing so by months so Month 10, 11, 12 show up after Month 1.

Comment: Use something like: `ORDER BY CAST(REPLACE(ColName,'Month','')AS INT)`