# Pivot Data in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have the below which gives me `SalesExVAT`, by `BranchNo` and by `FiscalWeek`

there is only 1 record per branch for each week:

```
Select 
        sa.BranchNo
        ,sa.FiscalWeek
        ,sa.SalesExVAT
    From
        dbo.SalesAggregateWeek sa
    Where 
        sa.FiscalYear = 2016
```

I wanted to display this in a Pivoted Format

I have tried the below,

```
Select 
    MyData.BranchNo

From
    (Select 
        sa.BranchNo
        ,sa.FiscalWeek
        ,sa.SalesExVAT
    From
        dbo.SalesAggregateWeek sa
    Where 
        sa.FiscalYear = 2016) MyData
Pivot
( sum(MyData.salesexvat)
  For 
    MyData.FiscalWeek In (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26
                    ,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52)  )
```

The desired out come would have the `FiscalWeek` as the headers along the top, the `BranchNo` displayed down the left, and `SalesExVAT` info as the data.

Any ideas on what I must do to correct my code are welcome as I've not used PIVOT yet.

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: it just doesn't work for me i must be missing something or doing it wrong

Comment: What is the issue? Based on your pivot, your headers are the Fiscal Week and this should work.

Comment: i want the fiscal week as the columns across the top, then the branch numbers displayed down the left,

Comment: What you can do in these cases is to use a dynamic column result rather than specifying each columns. Here's a sample: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query

Comment: You also need put the pivot values on your `SELECT .. [1], [2] ...` check basic example [**HERE**](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Do a SELECT * FROM (Select PIVOT STUFF HERE)

Comment: Guy Thank You very much, I have something that is now working, just need to work out how to order it !!

Comment: You only list `MyData.BranchNo` on your column list.  How do you expect the other columns to show?

Comment: Hi @Eric solved it now see answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Final Query Looks Like:

```
Select *

From 
    (Select 
            sa.BranchNo
            ,sa.FiscalWeek
            ,sa.SalesExVAT
        From
            dbo.SalesAggregateWeek sa
        Where 
            sa.FiscalYear = 2016)  P
Pivot 
        (Sum (SalesExVAT)
        For FiscalWeek In       
        (   [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],
            [18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30],[31],[32],
            [33],[34],[35],[36],[37],[38],[39],[40],[41],[42],[43],[44],[45],[46],[47],
            [48],[49],[50],[51],[52] )
        ) As pvt    ;
```

Key points:

The FiscalWeek Values all had to be in [Square Brackets]

The Pivot had to use an alias 'As pvt' and be finished with ;

If anyone knows a way I could have wrote `FiscalWeek Between 1 And 52` rather than state all the weeks please comment your answer.

Comment: As I answered on the top comment, use a dynamic pivot so you dont need to write FiscalWeek IN 1-52. Here's a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query

Comment: I did try that and it worked but I could not get it to order the weeks

Comment: Now that you are one step closer, here's a solution to your ordering https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122117/sql-dynamic-pivot-how-to-order-columns

Comment: @Isaiah3015 thank you, post it an answers if you want I'll accept it as correct

Comment: Thanks man. No need for my own answer. Edit your answer here and accept it (you can accept your own answer) with the code of dynamic pivot and dynamic order.  I'm glad it worked out.

Answer (score 1):

Here an option using a dynamic cross tab pivot...

```
DECLARE 
    @WeekColumns VARCHAR(8000) = '',
    @sql VARCHAR(8000) = '',
    @DeBug BIT = 1;     -- change to 0 to execute & 1 to print.

SELECT TOP 52
    @WeekColumns = CONCAT(@WeekColumns, ',
    [',t.n, '] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = ', t.n, ' THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END)')
FROM 
    dbo.tfn_Tally(52, 1) t;

SET @sql = CONCAT('
SELECT
    sa.BranchNo', 
    @WeekColumns, '
FROM
    dbo.SalesAggregateWeek sa
WHERE
    sa.FiscalYear = 2016;')

IF @DeBug = 1
BEGIN
    PRINT(@sql);
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
    EXEC(@sql);
END;
```

The print output...

```
SELECT
    sa.BranchNo,
    [1] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 1 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [2] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 2 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [3] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 3 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [4] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 4 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [5] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 5 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [6] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 6 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [7] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 7 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [8] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 8 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [9] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 9 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [10] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 10 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [11] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 11 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [12] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 12 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [13] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 13 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [14] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 14 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [15] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 15 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [16] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 16 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [17] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 17 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [18] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 18 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [19] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 19 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [20] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 20 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [21] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 21 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [22] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 22 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [23] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 23 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [24] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 24 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [25] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 25 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [26] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 26 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [27] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 27 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [28] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 28 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [29] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 29 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [30] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 30 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [31] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 31 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [32] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 32 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [33] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 33 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [34] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 34 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [35] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 35 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [36] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 36 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [37] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 37 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [38] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 38 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [39] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 39 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [40] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 40 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [41] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 41 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [42] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 42 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [43] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 43 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [44] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 44 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [45] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 45 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [46] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 46 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [47] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 47 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [48] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 48 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [49] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 49 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [50] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 50 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [51] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 51 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END),
    [52] = SUM(CASE WHEN sa.FiscalWeek = 52 THEN sa.SalesExVAT ELSE 0 END)
FROM
    dbo.SalesAggregateWeek sa
WHERE
    sa.FiscalYear = 2016;
```